# How does one interpret the plot wrap-up of Beasts of No Nation?

Tags: analysis, ending, beasts-of-no-nation

I recently saw Beasts of No Nation and I think it's a great movie be it fictional. Although I was quite intrigued by the ending I am unsure how to interpret it.

My initial reaction was to read the closing statement of the boy as a declaration of perspective to suggest that all child soldiers, at the end of the day, are still kids who belong to families and they should be treated with a certain level of compassion. Is this interpretation correct or am I missing something?